# Firefox blocked the ads

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a little problem with Firefox. I turned on the ad blocking and now things are not visible.
For example, social wrapper is not visible in Firefox, while in other browsers everything is normal. Also I have included a block on Google chrome but all is well. If someone has a good will to help me with my problem, thank you.

```
<div id='test'>

    </div>
    <div id='form-test'>
        <label>Name:</label>
        <div class='input'>
            <input type='text' name='name' class='txt_field' value='Name' />
        </div>
        <label>Email:</label>
        <div class='input'>
            <input type='text' name='email' class='txt_field'  value='example' />
        </div>
        <label>Comment:</label>
        <div class='input'>
            <textarea name='comment' cols='50' rows='10'></textarea>
        </div>
        <input type='submit' Value='Send' id='submit' />
    </div>

    <div class="social-wrapper">
        <footer>
            <div class="container clearfix">
                <ul class="list-social pull-right">
                      <li><a class="icon-1" href="#"></a></li>
                      <li><a class="icon-2" href="#"></a></li>
                      <li><a class="icon-3" href="#"></a></li>
                      <li><a class="icon-4" href="#"></a></li>
                      <li><a class="icon-5" href="#"></a></li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
        </footer>
     </div>
```

[I have problem with css, the link  for css:](http://www.test3.librax.net/social.css)

Comment: Is your domain name by any chance associated with an avalanche of spammy ads? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an exception in your ad blocker. While on your page, click on the icon of your ad-blocking extension (there should be one somewhere), and add your domain to the whitelist (ex add "librax.net*" to the whitelist), or click a button like "Don't block ads on this page". This would depend of the firefox addon you use.